# Excel logic - matching columns

Tags: vba, excel

My situation is the following:

[image]

The 'Day' column is 1 to 365, and each day is repeated 24 times (for the 24 hours). Each day and hour together have a Degree value, represented by the B column. I need to multiple the B column with the E column everytime A column matches D (eg. B2*E2, B3*E2, B4*E2, B7*E3).

How can I do that? I'm really confused here.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your shown example, in cell C2 and copied down:

`=B2*VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$366,2,FALSE)`

Comment: I'm trying it here but it's not working. Since the example I gave was not real, I need to understand what it does so I can apply it here. Can you explain it so I can try? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Vlookup is pulling the appropriate number from column E by matching A2 to column D, and then multiplying that number by B2.

Comment: I asked too early. I searched on Google what Vlookup did and ok.. understood your thought, but still not making it. I'm using LibreOffice. Do you think your formula doesn't work there?

Comment: I have verified that LibreOffice supports VLOOKUP (https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) so the same logic and formula should work.  I'd have to see an example of where it's not working, or a more clarity on what you're asking for (it's possible I misunderstood your requirement).

Comment: Yeah! It worked! Should've searched before asking.. again. The difference was semicolon instead of comma, and 0 instead of false. Great, man! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$366,2,FALSE)*B2

SUMPRODUCT(B2*($D$2:$D$366=A2)*$E$2:$E366)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Didn't try Sumproduct since Vlookup worked!